# What is the difference in meaning between “when there are” and “when there will be”

Tags: future-tense

> Finally, “when” can be used to provide further information about a particular point in time. Compare the following two sentences:
>
> - I will go jogging tomorrow when there are no cars in the streets.
> - I will go jogging tomorrow, when there will be no cars in the streets.
>
> [“Will” after “when” in English](https://jakubmarian.com/will-after-when-in-english/)

I don't see the difference in meaning between these 2 sentences.

In the second one the first action is "I will go jogging tomorrow "and the second action is the clause time .
So to indicate this ,the clause time takes the mark of the future whereas in the first one it is the contrary ,the clause time comes first .(no need for the future)
But in meaning I don't understand the difference.

Comment: The website you link to explains the difference. Without the comma "I will go jogging tomorrow [at a time] when there are no cars in the streets" says what time of day the jogger will choose. With the comma, "when there will be no cars in the streets' explains why the jogger is choosing tomorrow (perhaps the roads are being closed to traffic for some reason).

Comment: why with the comma and will it means "because", take this sentence "until you buy a new car you won't drive her to school " could I transform it in "Until you will buy a new car, you won't drive her to school" to explain why he can not drive her to school  or is it different

Comment: I don't know how I can explain the difference any more clearly than what the website tells you and what I have already said. The presence or absence of a comma makes no difference to the meaning of your sentence.

Comment: OK but the tense in the second sentence, the clause time takes the mark of the future "will "and  for me express the reason why he can't drive her to school as in the second example   "when there will be no car "

Comment: "When there will be no car" suggests that he is planning to get rid of his car, not buy a new one! A more idiomatic version would be "Until you get a new car you won't be able to drive her to school."

Comment: yes I know but what I 'd like to understand is why when the clause time takes the future" will "in one sentence (when there will be no car"........................................ it means because and not in my example because they are quite the same in term of grammar

Comment: In the 'jogging' example, 'when' doesn't _literally_ mean 'because'. 'When there will be no cars on the streets', as a separate clause, describes what tomorrow will be like and is the reason why the speaker is waiting until then to go jogging.